# Tableau calculated field - How do I select narrow down selections from tables?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am working on narrowing down the selection from three tables. The hierarchy looks like the link below.
PublisherAccountID includes a list of PublisherName, and within Publisher name, it contains a list of Imprint.

**PublisherAccountID > PublisherName > Publisher Imprint**

I am creating narrowing options for each hierarchy on Tableau.
For example, if I have two PublisherAccountID, A and B, A contains 1,2,3 while B contains 4,5,6. If I select A, then the option for PublisherName will now show 456.

Sorry I don't know how to not embed pciture link. The heiracy is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71KF9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you grouped the fields? You can always create a group. You can name the group from the 2nd level i.e. B, and group the relevant items (4,5,6). You can then use the new Group field as a filter.